# How to deal with relative links on the site?

Tags: http, request

Mojolicious does not distinguish these two requests:

```
GET /page
GET /page/
```

The same page is rendered.

But when rendered page has relative links you can fall into next trap.

For example if your `page` has:

```
<a href="trap">Trap</a>
```

And you click it for first request you will go to `/trap` page.
But when you click it for second request you will go to `/page/trap` page.

Should we do something with this or leave it as is?

Comment: I use the web server for remove the last trailing Slash. It's useful also for seo.

Comment: It's not a mojolicious or perl question. No one will answer you because your question not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just redirect the trailing slash to the non-trailing slash URL. I'm not sure what the 100% best solution would be, but something like

```
$self->redirect_to(
  $self->url_with->path($self->url_for->path->trailing_slash(0)))
  and return
  if $self->req->url->path->trailing_slash;
```

could be made to work.

This way /page/ is a 302 redirect to /page and /page displays the link, so it will always be consistent.

I agree with @Logioniz though in that this isn't really a Mojolicious problem.

Comment: in some cases it may be useful. But I like clue with web server as advised by @tempus71

Comment: Isn't this a working solution of what @tempus71 has described?

Comment: I like that solution

Comment: I think there's a language barrier here. Whose solution? Mine?

Comment: solution of tempus71: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349612/how-to-deal-with-relative-links-on-the-site/45590252?noredirect=1#comment77683534_45349612

Comment: What? That is literally the same solution as what I've written, only mine is a working copy/paste example of it. That is unless I've totally misread tempus71's statement.